# how to set Form authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication, form-authentication

I am aware of how to configure windows authentication using asp.net
My requirement is as soon as the web page loads it should redirect to login page and in login page i need to enter windows credentials then it should validate using windows authentication method and redirect me to original page.
Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

Answer (score 0):

in web.config add the following lines of code

```
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="indexpagename.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>
    </system.web>
```

Comment: Hi Shaik,Thank you. I understood from the above code that when i try to access the default page it redirectors to login.aspx page. My question is i have to enter windows credentials in login page and when i click on login it should validate for windows authentication. how to implement windows authentication by reading user credentials from login page?